# How to set colors of text in specifics cell in WPF DataGRID

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a method which comparing data in two dataTable.  After comparing I´d like to visualizing these compared data (which are in new DataTable called ChangeTab) in WPF dataGRID.

I´m filling datagrid from DataContext:

```
win.TableOfChange.DataContext = ChangeTab.DefaultView;
```

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Left"....
```

I´m fighting with problem, how to visualize data which are different (in the DataTables) by red, and data which are the same with green color - similar like is in the picture:

[image]

Is there is a way, how to do that (Set colour to WPF dataGRID cell for some red and some green from C#)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any business logic you use to set colors ?

Comment: No there isn't, it's mine proposal. I want visualize unchanged values by green color and changed values by red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you build the source table in the comparison process, if so you can easily store a boolean value that indicates equality. Then in the [`CellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle.aspx) you can use a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) on that property and have a [`Setter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.aspx) change the [`TextElement.Foreground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.foreground.aspx) property to the desired value.

Comment: @VilemRousi: Which binding? (MikeKulls' answer gives a good outline, you would just take that foreground binding into the `DataTrigger.Binding` without the converter of course)

Comment: thanks lot for your answer, I think is a good way, but I´m not sure about the Binding and I cannot solve it.
Because the result of comparing is just one row, I can add to this DataTable new row with comparing status (0-no change, 1-new value ,2-change). So the column of the comparing table (**name: treti**) has now 2 rows (value and comparing status).
The problem is with binding. I´m trying something like this:
`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding treti}" Value="0">
   <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Green"/>
 </DataTrigger>`
But this, doesn´t work. Please can you help me again?

Comment: @VilemRousi: You need to have the information on a cell level and apply the trigger at the cell level as well (`CellStyle`), working with full rows is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use DataTemplates for most columns in the grid. You would need to create a class, something like this:

```
class CellContent
{
    public object Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsDifferent { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a datatemplate something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="bob">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content}" TextElement.Foreground="{Binding Path=IsDifferent, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
<DataTemplate>
```

You then assign the template to each column.

The other option which is probably better would be to use a Trigger to change the colour if the IsDifferent is true.